# Как пересоздать объект в JavaScript? Правильно ли это делаю я?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Осваиваю программирование на JS, и запутался с переиспользованием объекта. Прошу помочь разобраться.
К примеру создаю объект (знаю, что синтаксис старый, но это требования ПО, в котором пишу на JS).
Что-то пишу в его свойства, что-то с объектом делаю. Далее, мне надо проделать все то же самое, но  записать в объект новые значения свойств. Я не хочу плодить новые объекты, а хочу использовать уже имеющийся. Правильно ли будет просто "переобъявить" его, так как это делаю я? Или лучше будет в цикле пробежаться по свойствам объекта и обнулить их?

```
var FuncObj = function (userName, age) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.age = age;
};

//Создаю объект 
var newFuncObj = new FuncObj("Vasya", 25);

//что-то делаю с ним

//пересоздаю объект
var newFuncObj = new FuncObj("Petya", 30);
```

Comment: `new FuncObj("Petya", 30);` — ты создал новый объект. То что ты записал его в ту же переменную неважно. При этом если никаких ссылок на старый объект не осталось, то JS сам его удалит и памяти. Заниматься ручным освобождением памяти не нужно.

Comment: Понял. Большое спасибо!